# Nuget error during build

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget

I grabbed this repo [CommandLIneParser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline.git)

and opened it in Visual Studio 2017.  Build fails because Nuget fails.  In the nuget package manager I see messages like this:

```
Dependency '"CommandLine": {
  "target": "project"
}' has invalid version specification.
```

What does that mean and how can I resolve it?

Second problem (may be caused by the first). During build I get this error:

> Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: Invalid restore input.
>   UAP projects must contain exactly one target framework. Input files:
>   C:\Users\Jerry\Source\Repos\commandline\tests\CommandLine.Tests\CommandLine.Tests.csproj,
>   C:\Users\Jerry\Source\Repos\commandline\tests\CommandLine.Tests\project.json.

but both projects do, in fact, target the same framework (.net 4.5, in this case).  So I'm guessing that the error message means something else?

Update:

Now that I'm looking at the two files in the error message, I'm getting a clue:

CommandLine.Tests.csproj has:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.5;net40;net45</TargetFrameworks>
```

project.json has:

```
  "testRunner": "xunit",

    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "buildOptions": {
                "define": [ "PLATFORM_DOTNET", "SKIP_FSHARP" ],
                "keyFile": "../../CommandLine.snk"
            },
```

So I see the mismatch.  But that just leaves me with the somewhat-rhetorical question:  "How did the last version ever build?"

Comment: As I test, all those issues should comes from the `CommandLine.Tests` project, if I remove or unload it, solution build fine. But I could not find the "CommandLine.Tests.csproj has:<TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.5;net40;net45</TargetFrameworks>", I open the test project file, find it target.net 4.5 framework:https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/blob/286b724c114706274a2a629e7aba714c172140ce/tests/CommandLine.Tests/CommandLine.Tests.csproj#L13.

Comment: Again, AFAIK, When  using the old (non-sdk) project format for a f# project, always get the error: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/5931. So the project itself may has some unfixed problems, This may be the reason it is called "test". Anyway, since this issue is more related to the project itself, I suggest you can discuss this issues with the author of this project on GitHub.No one knows these issues better than the author himself.